# Can't access wp-admin page, getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTIONS (Tried everything!)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, ftp

So the site was working fine just last week. Today I tried to access the wp-admin page to log in and after slow loading, for a bit, I get an error saying it was redirecting too many times and failed. After lots of research, I tried every method the other articles suggested but nothing worked.

Here is what I tried:

1. Cleared out my cookies, and cache
2. Tried other laptops & phones
3. Used a VPN to see if it was my ISP somehow
4. Disabled all plugins by renaming the plugins folder
5. Disabled the theme by renaming the themes folder
6. Deleted `.htaccess` file but all that did was cause the `wp-admin` page to display a `403 Forbidden page`. After loading the normal site (aka: mysite.com) the `.htaccess` got regenerated and I was back at square one.
7. Added this code to wp-config.php as per this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/302965/too-many-redirects-only-when-trying-to-access-wp-admin-page (Tried at the top of the file and the end).

   ```
   if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
     $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
   ```
8. Tried to define `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` in `wp-config.php`

None of the above worked and none fixed it. Please note only the wp-admin page has this issue. The site itself loads but I can't access the admin page which is a disaster and I don't know what to do. I hope one of you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: This could be many things with Wordpress - check redirects on a site like https://wheregoes.com/ -- Also try to go to https://yoursite/wp-login.php rather than the wp-admin -- Ultimately it is usually plugins, cache or htaccess error- if you are using a CDN disable plugins, clear server cache then try to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might be facing this issue, the culprit was the `.htaccess` file under the `wp-admin` folder. It had a Deny from all written in it which blocked access to everything. Not sure what added it since I definitely did not. When I changed it to Allow from all it worked fine.